# ReferenceError: todoItem is not defined Backbone + CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I'm trying to use backbone with coffeescript instead javascript:

```
TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend(
  toggleStatus: ->
    if @.get 'status' is "incomplete"
      @.set 'status': 'complete' 
    else
      @.set 'status': 'incomplete'
    @.save()  
    )

todoItem = new TodoItem(
  description: 'I play the guitar'
  status: 'incomplete'
  id: 1
)

TodoView = Backbone.View.extend(
  tagName: 'div'
  id: "box"
  className: 'red-box'

  events: 
    "click h3": "alertStatus"
    'change input': 'toggleStatus'

  template: 
    _.template "<h3> <input type=checkbox #{ print "checked" if status is "complete"} /> <%= description %></h3>"

  initialize: ->
    @.model.on 'change', @.render, @
    @.model.on 'destroy', @.remove, @

  toggleStatus: ->
    @.model.toggleStatus()

  alertStatus: ->
    alert('Hey you clicked the h3!')

  remove: ->
    @.$el.remove()

  render: ->
    @.$el.html @.template(@.model.toJSON())
)

todoView = new TodoView({model: todoItem})
todoView.render()
console.log todoView.el
```

If I try in console:

```
todoItem.set({description: 'asdfadfasdfa'});
```

I get:

```
ReferenceError: todoItem is not defined
```

Also, I can't see inside of my body the div:

```
<div id="box" class="red-box">
  <h3>
  <input type="checkbox" undefined>
  "I play the guitar"
  </h3>
 </div>
```

But I can see this div in my console fine.

**Where is it the error?**

Thank you!

Comment: Afaik underscore makes all variables local, so you won't be able to access them from the console without declaring them explicitly global.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*I can't see inside of my body the div*"?

Comment: Thank you, I mean that the `<div id="box" class="red-box">...` is not rendered inside of my html page. Can you paste a example for fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What code is supposed to append the `$el` to the DOM, or use dom elements for the View initially?

Comment: It use dom elements for the View initially! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the nice things about CoffeeScript is that you can use `@foo` instead of `@.foo`. A little less to write and a little nicer to read.

---

You don't have to use Backbone's `.extend()`, because CoffeeScript has classes that work in a completely compatible manner:

```
class TodoView extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'div'
  id: 'box' # don't do this if you have more than one TodoView on the page at once
  className: 'red-box'
```

---

`todoItem` isn't defined because CoffeeScript will wrap all of your code in an "immediately executed function expression", which prevents leaking variables to the global scope (this is a good thing). From the docs:

> Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function: `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident.

If you want to inspect local variables, set a breakpoint in Chrome's debugger or Firebug.

---

I'm worried about this code:

```
_.template "... #{ print "checked" if status is "complete"} ..."
```

What is `print`? Where have you defined that? For that matter, where is `status`? Do you mean `@status`?

---

Finally, the reason you're not seeing the `div` is that you never added it to the DOM. `.render()` renders the element...but it doesn't automatically insert it on the page for you. You have to do that yourself:

```
todoView.render()
$('body').append(todoView.el) # (or wherever you want it to go)
```